What is the likelihood that significant unearthed prehistoric settlements exist beneath cities with continuous habitation?
Considering the comparatively rapid accumulation of soil layers over time, which has led to the burial of structures such as the Easter Island statues and Harappan sites, what is the likelihood(based on your professional knowledge and intuition) that significant (comparable to the discovery of the Indus Valley civilization) unearthed prehistoric settlements exist beneath cities with continuous habitation, such as Varanasi or Istanbul?


What is your definition of "significant" here? E.g. I think in Berlin several prehistoric settlements have been found, even though it is situated in a region where natural resources (esp. food) are far from abundant.

@A.Random If you edit the question to include the details from your first comment and also give some clarification of what "significant" means in the context of this question (i.e. does it mean of local interest or world-wide importance or something in between?) then you should be able to get it re-opened.

Extension of comment from @Jan: The old city hall was torn down in 1865 and extended further north than now. They simply left the foundations in place since it would be underneath the street (and then forgotten). When the building of the underground started in that area around 2009 they were surprised at what they found. Altes Berliner Rathaus - Berlin.de (in German)

Is there anyone who would argue that the probability is less than 100%?

@MCW Looking at how much construction has been going on in Istanbul (subways etc.), I would argue the chances that there is another Pompeii hidden underneath are small. Another Stonehenge might theoretically be possible though?

The fact that no continuously inhabited city exists over Stonehenge or Göbekli Tepe proves that the correlation between significant sites chosen by prehistoric individuals and those chosen for placement of historic cities is not 1:1. The List of oldest continuously inhabited cities is extensive, and shows the meaninglessness of the term to start with.  This question is vastly too broad, and can not be answered by an authoritative answer. We can not guess what lies under some random city.

@justCal Not 1:1, but there certainly is some correlation? E.g. both historically and prehistorically access to food and water has been a necessary precondition for significant settlements. Fords and natural harbours have a high likelyhood of settlements forming nearby. Etc.

Yes, but now we are guessing which ones were so chosen, Both the Romans and Mongols places waystations along roads to support logistics. Many of these locations would be chosen specifically for location, distance of a days march or a horses expected distance run from another location, not for ease of access to resources needed for survival that a prehistoric settlement would require. These central locations still developed into later major European cities with a long history of habitation, but we should have very little expectation to find an older settlement beneath them.

I live in the Czech Republic. Many cities and towns have on their territory known prehistoric settlements. Practically everywhere, where there were no bogs then.

Before this question gets closed (again):

What is the likelihood that significant unearthed prehistoric settlements exist beneath cities with continuous habitation?

Very likely
People are creatures of habit and therefore have needs and desires that over the generations do not fundamentally change.
So if one generation finds an area that is habitable, then it will likely be that a future generation will also find it  habitable and will build on (or over) existing settlements.
They may not know (or care) that the previous generation became extinct due to the efforts of an (self proclaimed) 'all knowledgeable, superior, beings' (themselves now extinct) to eradicate everything that does not fulfill their stringent conditions to justify the further existence of that settlement.

'Want to improve this answer?' No, the answer speaks for itself for those who have a basic understanding of history and (at least) a grain of common sense (both of which do not require 'citations to explain why this answer is correct').

OTOH there are also a number of examples where later generations did not find a place as attractive as their ancestors. E.g. Babylon, Angkor Wat, or Merv.
